# how to solve a system of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

> prove nPr - nP(r-­1) = (n - r)*nP(r-­1)

**I've attempted this problem in vain without any solution and I do not really understand why and I was wondering if you could correct my steps**

*My steps:*

LHS= $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}-\frac{n!}{(n-r+1)!}$

$\frac{n!*(n-r+1)!}{(n-r)!(n-r+1)!}-\frac{(n!)}{(n-r)!(n-r+1)}$

but then that simplifies down back to:

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)}!-\frac{n!}{(n-r+1)!}$

I thus was wondering where i was making my mistakes

Comment: Do you want a numeric proof, similar to what you attempted, or a combinatorial proof, coming from the definition?

Comment: @RoryDaulton combinatorial would be great, i'll upvote if it is correct and good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think back to the definition of a permutation.

Suppose you have 5 objects $A, B, C, D,$ and $E$. Now, $^5P_3$ is how many ways you can pick $3$ objects, in which order matters. How would you compute this by hand, without using the permutation formula? For the first object, you would have $5$ choices, for the second one, you would have $4$ choices, and for the last one you would have $3$ choices, so $5\times4\times3$ would be how many ways you could pick $3$ objects.

Now, we can look back at the original question. We can simplify the expression to $^nP_r=(n-r+1) \times ^nP_{r-1}$. Looking back at what we did in the last paragraph, we can see that $^5P_2 = 5\times4$, and $^5P_3 + 5\times4\times3$. Notice a pattern? We can infer that $^5P_4 = 5\times4\times3\times2$, and this is indeed correct. Now we can see that $(n-r+1)$ is really just the next number in the pattern; in other words, we can say $^5P_3 = (5-3+1) \times (5\times4)$, which simplifies to $5\times4\times3$.

That would finish the proof.